# JavaScript - setter, but with bucklet

Tags: javascript

I have a problem I have this setter,:

```
set settings({radius,maxZoom,extent}){
    this._radius = radius;
    this._maxZoom = maxZoom;
    this._extent = extent;
  }
```

Now how can i can use it

```
object.settings = ????
```

Comment: `object.settings = { radius: 1, maxZoom: 2, extent: 3 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you find constants surrounded with curly-brackets

```
settings({ radius, maxZoom, extent })
```

or

```
const { radius, maxZoom, extent } = settings
```

it's called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) a simpler way to write code...

using your example

```
set settings({radius,maxZoom,extent}){
  this._radius = radius;
  this._maxZoom = maxZoom;
  this._extent = extent;
}
```

is the same as

```
set settings(settings) {
  this._radius = settings.radius;
  this._maxZoom = settings.maxZoom;
  this._extent = settings.extent;
}
```

and you still need to pass

```
 // this
const mySettings = { radius: 1, maxZoom: 2, extent: 3 }
object.settings = mySettings

// or directly as this
object.settings = { radius: 1, maxZoom: 2, extent: 3 }
```